# Onchange picker show radio buttons. Here is my code

Tags: swiftui

There will be multiple pickers, on change of each picker need to
show different radio button list options. Once we select other picker new radio button list will appear and old one will be removed.

```
// Radio button select deselect.
    struct SelectionIndicator: View {
            private let isSelected: Bool
            init(isSelected: Bool) {
                self.isSelected = isSelected
            }
            var body: some View {
                if isSelected {
                    // Show a round shape with a transparent tick
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 20 , height: 20 )
                } else {
                    // Just show an empty ring
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel))
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .padding(2)
                }
            }
        }
        
        struct ContentView: View {
            var Country = [ "India", "Australia", "Bangladesh", "Germany"]
            var City = [ "Rome", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York"]
            @State private var selectedDestOne = "Select"
            @State private var city = ""
            

   // Function for radio button
            private func radioButtonItem(choice: String) -> some View {
                HStack {
                    SelectionIndicator(isSelected: city == choice)
                    Text(choice)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation { city = choice }
                }
            }
            
            var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    Text("Destination 1")
                    Picker("Select", selection: $selectedDestOne) {
                        ForEach(City, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: selectedDestOne,
                              perform: { item in
                        ForEach(0..<City.count, id: \.self) { city in
                            radioButtonItem(choice: City[city])
                        }
                    })
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
```

Can I create any view inside Picker onchange? outside onchange  radio button code is working fine. Need help regarding this.

Comment: Your code isn’t compilable, so it’s not possible to give a direct/complete answer unless you provide a [mre], but the primary issue looks like you’re trying to use view hierarchy inside the onChange closure. Instead, use that closure for procedural instructions and reflect those changes in your view hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, I have removed the dependency. You can compile the code now

Comment: You are still trying to put views inside the onChange closure

Answer (score 0):

Make the second list of options (cities) dependent on the value of the selected country. If that is an @State variable, the view will re-render. No need to use .onchange

```
import SwiftUI

struct Country : Hashable {
    let name : String
    let cities : [String]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var countries = [
        Country(name: "India", cities: ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Mumbao"]),
        Country(name: "Germany", cities: ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"])
    ]
    @State private var selectedCountry : Country
    @State private var selectedCity : String? = nil
    
    init() {
        selectedCountry = countries[0]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Destination 1")
            Picker("Select", selection: $selectedCountry) {
                ForEach(countries, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            
            Text("City")
            Picker("Select", selection: $selectedCity) {
                ForEach(selectedCountry.cities, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```